# Вывод сообщения в той же строке C++

Tags: c++, вывод

Написал код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//шаблон ./a.out <пречисление ip через пробел> -i <перечисление интерфейсов через пробел> <путь к папке для сохранения результатов пингов> <количество сколько раз нужно повторять пинг> 
    if(argc<6){cerr<<"invalid argument"; exit(1);}

    vector<string> gen, ips, intrs;
    string str, path, times;
    int mark=1, tm;
    path=getenv("HOME");
    path+="/";
    path+= argv[argc-2];
    std::filesystem::create_directories(path);
    tm=atoi(argv[argc-1]);
    if(tm<1){tm=1;;}
    else{tm=atoi(argv[argc-1]);}

    for(int i=mark; i<argc-2;i++){
        str=argv[i];
        if(str=="-i"){
            i+=1;
            for(mark=i;mark<argc-2;mark++){
                str=argv[mark];
                intrs.push_back(str);
            }
        }
        ips.push_back(str);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<intrs.size();i++){
        ips.pop_back();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<ips.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<intrs.size();j++){
            mark=0;
            cout<< "starting ping. please wait\n";
            while(mark<tm){
                puts("#");         //<----'Как вывести # без перевода строки?'
                system(("ping -I "+intrs[j]+" "+ips[i]+" -s 65000 -c 50 >>"+path+"/"+ips[i]+"_from_"+intrs[j]).c_str());
                mark++;
            }
            cout << "ping "<<ips[i]<<" from "<<intrs[j]<<" "<<tm<<" times DONE\n";
            system(("\ngrep 'loss' "+path+"/"+ips[i]+"_from_"+intrs[j]).c_str());
        }
    }
    ips.clear();
    ips.shrink_to_fit();
    intrs.clear();
    intrs.shrink_to_fit();
    gen.clear();
    gen.shrink_to_fit();
    return 0;
}
```

Хочется мне, чтобы # выводилась как, например, при установке пакетов через какой-нибудь apt или yum в linux-е. Т.е в той же строке прибавлялась а не в следующей. Что то никак не могу додуматься. В коде коммент оставил, где именно выводится #.
Нужно чтоб каждый проход цикла while в вывод добавлялось #

Comment: @EOF так выводит  все в одну строку,  но только после полного завершения программы. А нужно чтоб каждый проход цикла while в вывод добавлялось #

Comment: Используйте `std::fputs`, `std::puts` добавляет перевод строки, в доках же написано

Comment: `cout << '#' << flush;`

Comment: @dIm0n не понял как это удовлетворит мою хотелку и совсем не понял, как это использовть с моей программой. Я погуглил и это вроде как в файл запсь. Но пасиба

Comment: @EOF Да. То что нужно. Огонь!

Comment: @umd ничего гуглить не надо, всегда начинайте с доков https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputs, там внизу пример как раз

Comment: @dIm0n Посмотрел все. Попробовал. Не сомневаюсь, что лыжи то едут. Но я не могу понять как мне это использовать, чтобы отработало так же как `flush`.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `puts` автоматически переводит строку после отображения своего аргумента. Чтобы вывести один символ и не переводить строку можно написать так:

```
cout << '#';
```

или

```
cout.put('#');
```

Чтобы не ждать заполнения буфера и отобразить символ немедленно, необходимо сбросить буфер. Для этого необходимо использовать `flush`. Например так:

```
cout << '#' << flush;
```